# How do I copy only 20170906.1 from the text file by using batch file

Tags: batch-file, text, copy, command

Hi I wanted to Copy only **20170906.1** from the demo.txt file which contain **\tfs-server\TFSBUILDS\OB-MAINMVC2.0\OB-MAINMVC2.0_20170906.1\_PublishedWebsites\In.OfficeBox.Api.Task\bin** and keep it in another txt file whether 20170906.1 is dynamic value it will change every day how do I get value after `_` and before `\`

Comment: Don't you mean "after `_` and before `_`"? Because as you have it now, you'd get  "20170906.1_PublishedWebsites"...

Comment: @JuhaK Yes 'after _ and before _' means only value i.e 20170906.1

Comment: `for /F "tokens=2 delims=_" %%a in (demo.txt) do > anotherFile.txt echo %%a`

Comment: @Aacini this gives me, **20170906.1\ I wanted just 20170906.1** I have eddied the Question according

Comment: I am confused. My `for` code correctly returns the desired result using the data _of your original question_. You even validated such a data in your reply to JuhaK's comment! Are you trying to say that you did a mistake and the original data was wrong, so you ask me to fix my code accordingly? Because in your comment it seems that you said that my code was wrong... **`:(`**

Comment: @Aacini Yes my original data was wrong `:(` by mistake I miss the \ from data, am so sorry for that but I have modified the data so now the data is correct. Can you please fix your code for me Please